# Dockerized nginx and django on Apache installed VPS

Tags: django, docker, nginx, vps

I'm trying to deploy my dockerized django project with nginx container to a VPS server which has apache. Nginx conf with 80 port, I'm getting `port already in use`  error. Therefore, I've changed my config as following.

nginx.conf;

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name sub.example.com;
    resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off valid=10s;


    charset utf-8;

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yml;

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  nginx:
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: './Dockerfile'
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - staticfiles:/var/www/static
    container_name: nginx
    depends_on:
      - app

  app:
    image: core
    build: ./
    restart: always
    container_name: app
    command: bash -c "python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && python manage.py migrate && gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 core.wsgi:application --reload"
    volumes:
      - ./storage/assets/staticfiles:/app/storage/assets/staticfiles
      - staticfiles:/app/storage/assets/staticfiles/
      - .:/app
    expose:
      - 8000
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - redis

  redis:
    restart: always
    image: redis:latest
    expose:
      - "6379"

  worker:
    build: ./
    command: celery -A core worker -l info -Q celery
    environment:
      - C_FORCE_ROOT=true
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - redis
  
  beat:
    build: ./
    command: celery -A core beat -l info
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    links:
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - redis

volumes:
  staticfiles:
```

When I build and run the project on VPS server with the commands below, there is no error.

```
sudo docker build -t core:latest .
sudo docker run -d -p 8000:8080 core:latest
```

When I check the images with `docker images`, I can see my image. However, when I check the running containers by running `docker ps`, I cannot see my container and my subdomain redirects me to the main domain.

Could you please help me with this?